# Application lifecycle wrong when I change statusBarOrientation

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

when i call `UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarOrientation(.landscapeRight, animated: true)`

app into the background and go back, print

"ApplicationWillResignActive"

"ApplicationDidBecomeActive"

"ApplicationWillResignActive"

"ApplicationDidBecomeActive"

why ?  I only have two action

```
@objc fileprivate func handleApplicationWillResignActive() {
    debugPrint("ApplicationWillResignActive")
    if self.playerPlayStatus == .playing {
        self.currentPlayTime = self.player.currentTime()
        self.player.pause()
    }
}

@objc fileprivate func handleApplicationDidBecomeActive() {
    debugPrint("ApplicationDidBecomeActive")
    switch self.playerPlayStatus {
        case .pause:
            self.player.seek(to: self.currentPlayTime, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero, completionHandler: { (finished) in
                if finished {
                    self.player.play()
                }
            })
        default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: i think this is a bug created by apple? although i call the deprecated function

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationWillResignActive and Background both are different things. Even application in foreground application can become Inactive.
So please brief out, What do you want to do?

Comment: when background pause the player, foreground play

Comment: The crux of the problem is I only have two action, but you see the output content

Comment: Pause in enter background method and play in ApplicationDidBecomeActive